# Plot output from provenance package in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density

I would like to plot the output from the *provenance* package using ggplot2.
Specifically, the output from the function *KDE()* which results in a class *KDE*. (It uses an adaptive bandwidth for the KDE, which is why I cannot use the kde estimate from ggplot2)

```
install.packages("provenance")
library(provenance)

data(Namib)
samp <- Namib$DZ$x[['N1']]
dens <- KDE(samp,0,3000,kernel="epanechnikov")
```

I would like to plot the output in *dens* using ggplot2, however the class *KDE* is not supported by ggplot2.

Is there a way to extract the information needed to plot the density estimate in ggplot2?
I tried to look at the structure of the class *KDE*, however, I cannot figure out how or what to extract.
dens$x, I think, is where the x-component is stored, and the y-component in dens$y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access the pieces you need with '$'. Just combine those to into a data frame and have that be your ggplot data.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = dens$x,y =  dens$y), aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point()
```